# Do we still need "placement new" and "operator new"?

Tags: c++

It seems that allocator does the same work as “placement new” and “operator new”.
and its interface is  more convenient.

For example:

```
string *ps = static_cast<string *>(operator new(sizeof(string)));
new (ps) string("Hello");
cout<<*ps<<endl;
```

can be rewritten to

```
allocator<string> as;
string *ps2 = as.allocate(1);
as.construct(ps2,"Hello");
cout<<*ps2<<endl;
```

So it that means that "placement new" and "operator new" are obsolete?

Comment: For backwards compatibility.

Comment: Specifically, `allocator` needs both `placement new` and `operator new` in order to do what it does.  I would say they aren't "obsolete", but rather, should not be used in client code.

Comment: Placement new is indeed use able, specifically in free standing environments, such as embedded systems and oses.

Comment: What if you cannot possibly afford to have an exception? `std::allocator` throws. How do you place an object at a particular location? `std::allocator` allows for a hint, but technically it's just that, a _hint_. Placement new places the object exactly where you want it, always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are still needed. How else would you implement your custom allocator? ;)

Edit:

This answer deserves more explanation:

If you take a look at the std::allocator's `construct` member function you can see that it uses the placement new operator.

So, the responsibility of an allocator is to allocate uninitialized storage big enough for the object via member function `allocate`, and then "in-place" construct it into this storage via its `construct` member. The latter is performed using placement new.